# Making an HTML Tablerow that contains a phpmyadmin tablerow selectable to send information to edit.php through a form submission with method post

Tags: php, mysql, input, html-table, datatable

So i made a dynamic table and now i want to make the table rows selectable (max 1) and send the information to the next page where u can edit the phpmyadmin tablerow that you selected through the dynamic table. But only if its not too complicated, otherwise i'll just make it editable through the dynamic table itself.

This is what i got so far:

```
<form action="edit.php" method="post">
    <div class="table">
        <table cellspacing="0">
            <tr class="top">
                <th>Titel</th>
                <th>Auteur</th>
                <th>ISBN13</th>
                <th>Uitgever</th>
                <th>Pagina's</th>
                <th>ID</th>
            </tr>
        <?php

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM books";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0){
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                ?> 
                <tr>
                    <th><?php echo $row['title']; ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo $row['author']; ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo $row['isbn13']; ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo $row['publisher']; ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo $row['pages']; ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo $row['id']; ?></th>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, maar er zijn nog geen boeken in het assortiment.";
        }

        $conn->close();
        ?>
        </table>
    </div>
<button class="continue" type="submit">Doorgaan</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You have to have  a form element and button for every row. and you can add  for every Form <input type"hiddn" with row['id'] then you have a dynamic way to send a specific id to edit.php, that what you have is only good when you have one book after the select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add 1 more column for edit button action button like so :

```
<th><a href="url/editbook.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Edit</a></th>
```

This will provide a clickable link to, for example, url/editbook.php?id=1.
From here you can create editbook.php page and create form to edit the content of the selected book.

In editbook.php you have to query for the selected book id. Something like this :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE id = $_GET['id']";
```

I hope you understand what i'm trying to say.

P/S : Don't forget to sanitize. You can find some reference in this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/how-can-i-sanitize-user-input-with-php)

Comment: this is what i've done in edit.php (for other people to use too)

```$sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE id =".$_GET['id'];
$result = $conn->query($sql);
 if ($result->num_rows > 0){
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
?>
<div class="panel">
<form class="edit">
ul>
<li>Titel<input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['title']; ?>"></li>
</ul>
<button type="submit">Opslaan</button>
</form>
<?php
 }
} else {
echo "ERROR";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: since you are querying for one result, use [fetch_row()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) instead. And its a good practice not to mix up too much PHP code with HTML code. It will make your code much cleaner and easy to maintain.